# Can I backup my Windows partition with Acronis and then reinstall it inside a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Currently I use Windows 7, which is located on the C partition.
Can I just use Acronis to backup the entire C partition, then install Ubuntu 12.04, set up VirtualBox under Ubuntu and then restore C partition (Windows 7 and all programs) using Acronis inside VirtualBox?

Comment: Have you considered a dual-boot?

Answer (score 2):

No ; Windows is not nearly as forgiving as a modern Linux when moved between hardware - and VirtualBox is a machine composed of "Virtual" hardware that is almost certainly not compatible with your current real hardware.

You should look at this page : https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows

Comment: Is it easier and more logical to do a new installation of Windows 7 inside VirtualBox and Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Marko it would be a lot easier to just install it in virtual box. An add the software or media you had on your windows partition . On a side note vmware has tools that can do what you are looking.  If you are willing to pay for it that is.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Windows 7 is VERY forgiving about hardware changes.  I backed-up an image from a Pentium Core 2 Duo (2007 hardware) and restored it to a Pentium i5 machine (2012 hardware).  Mind you, the drivers were all similar (nVidia graphics, Asus Mobo, Intel CPU)... but many new drivers were installed/downloaded on first-boot. Nevertheless, it worked quite well, especially after I went into the device manager and deleted all of the old unused drivers.  You'd think it would be quite successful on a VM due to the simplified virtual (and universally generic) devices the VM uses.  But I wouldn't expect anything spectacular out of it (ie gaming).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the latest version (Acronis True Image 2013) with the "Plus Pack". It has the "Universal Restore (tm)" feature which supports restoring with different hardware.

> *from Acronis True Image 2013 Plus Pack Data Sheet:*
>   Restore to Dissimilar Hardware
>   Restore a computer to
>   dissimilar hardware
>   regardless of make, model,
>   or installed components, or
>   to a **virtual machine**.

I didn't try it with a virtual machine, but it worked for a normal PC.